# Number of blocks to spit range of values over 64

Tags: java, arrays, math, integer, integer-division

I have the following piece of code:

```
long[] blocks = new long[(someClass.getMemberArray().length - 1) / 64 + 1];
```

Basically the `someClass.getMemberArray()` can return an array that could be much larger than 64 and the code tries to determine how many blocks of len 64 are needed for subsequent processing.
I am confused about the logic and how does this work. It seems to me that just doing:

```
 long[] blocks = new long[(int) Math.ceil(someClass.getMemberArray().length / 64.0)];
```

should work too any looks simpler.
Can someone help me understanding the `-1` and `+1` reasoning in the original snippet, how it works and if the `ceil` would fail in some cases?

Answer (score 1):

as you correctly commented, the -1/+1 is required to get the correct number of blocks, including only partially filled ones. It effectively rounds up.

(But it has something that could be considered a bug: if the array has length 0, which would required 0 blocks, it returns 1. This is because integer division usually truncates on most systems, i.e. rounds UP for negative numbers, so (0 - 1)/64 yields 0. However, this may be a feature if zero blocks for some reasons are not allowed. It definitively requires a comment though.)

The reasoning for the first, original line is that it only uses integer arithmetics, which should translate on just a few basic and fast machine instructions on mostcomputers.

The second solution involved casting floating-point arithmetic and casting. Traditionally, floating-point arithmetic was MUCH slower on most processors, which probably was the reasoning for the first solution. However, on modern CPUs with integrated floating-point support, the performance depends more on other things like cache lines and pipelining.

Personally, I don't really like both solutions, as it's not really obvious what they do. So I would suggest the following solution:

```
int arrayLength = someClass.getMemberArray().length;
int blockCount = ceilDiv(arrayLength, 64);
long[] blocks = new long[blockCount];

//...

/**
 * Integer division, rounding up.
 * @return the quotient a/b, rounded up.
 */
static int ceilDiv(int a, int b) {
    assert b >= 0 : b; // Doesn't work for negative divisor.

    // Divide.
    int quotient = a / b;

    // If a is not a multiple of b, round up.
    if (a % b != 0) {
        quotient++;
    }

    return quotient;
}
```

It's wordy, but at least it's clear what should happen, and it provides a general solution which works for all integers (except negative divisors). Unfortunately, most languages don't provide an elegant "round up integer division" solution.

Comment: I like your solution much better, than you so much for posting this. I would also like to understand the original idea of the first one. I mean what is the intuition behind that -1/+1? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the -1 would be necessary, but the +1 is likely there to rectify the case where the result of the division gets rounded down to the nearest non-decimal value (which should be, well, every case except those where the result is without decimals)

Comment: If `someClass.getMemberArray().length` is 64 then without the subtraction the result would be `2` instead of 1. So the calculation is correct. I am bit confused on the intuition behind this